# When should noun modifiers be plural and when singular?

Tags: nouns, modifiers

As far as I know noun modifiers should be singular. For example:

- 40 person team - the person is singular even though it's multiple persons

However, there are some cases in which a noun modifier will be plural. Example:

- special operations team
- special needs children

Why are the singular and plural cases different?

Comment: Perhaps this has something to do with the modifier being in 'base case' rather than 'singular'. Maybe "special ops" is the base case; "special operation" is something else altogether. Likewise for "special needs". (*I don't have the full answer, so I just offer this observation. If someone does come up with a full answer, please ping me about it*.)

Comment: The noun modifiers to which you refer are nouns themselves. This means that they can (but perhaps not always) follow the normal singular/plural convention. So whether you said "event organiser", or "events organiser", would depend on whether there was to be one "event" or multiple "events".

Comment: Having said that, I am a member of a committee which sponsors six lectures a year. And the person arranging the speakers is known as the "Lecture Secretary" not "Lectures Secretary".  So the exact position does depend on an idiomatic principle, I suspect.

Comment: "A Six-Foot, 220-Pound Penguin Once Lived in New Zealand"

Comment: @WS2 But person is also a noun itself, so why 40 person team and not 40 persons team?

Comment: @Kris Can you elaborate on the differences?

Comment: @GEV The simple answer is that I don't know, and I am not sure anyone does.  Suffice it to say that English idiomatic speech was not designed by logicians and programmers - nor does it have the consistency of Latin nor the languages most closely descended from it. (Though I am happy enough to bow to linguistic expertise of anyone who thinks they do know the answer.)

Comment: The problem seems to be what a noun modifier is, and what singular means, either of which might be better addressed somewhere such as English Language Users.
As you’re here “special operations team" and "special needs children" are simply wrong.
A noun is not a phrase. “A team conducting special operations” or “children with special needs” would be fine but you changed too much by switching suffixed adjectival phrases into prefixed adjectival nouns.
Your “40 person team” isn’t singular; it’s simply an error.
The correct “40-person team” takes no account of grammatical number.

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I know noun modifiers should be singular.

This is right, but plural nouns or noun phrases can "attributively" modify a singular noun.  [Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct).

This is what's happening with both your examples.