# Is the plural correct in "Russian Warcrimes House"?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, attributive-nouns

Is it grammatical? Usually, noun modifiers take a singular form except when it changes the meaning ("right abuses" v. "rights abuses")

[image: sign with "warcrimes" added between the words "Russian House"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### tl;dr

Yes, it is grammatically correct.

### Explanation

A similar question about the general rule is answered [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/178099/when-should-noun-modifiers-be-plural-and-when-singular#:%7E:text=on%20this%20post.-,As%20far%20as%20I%20know%20noun%20modifiers%20should%20be%20singular,attributively%22%20modify%20a%20singular%20noun.).

In this specific case, there is some [context](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/2022/05/23/davos-russia-house-zelensky-world-economic-forum/) - the sign normally says "Russian House" but the building has been rented for an art exhibit and the sign has been temporarily changed to "Russian Warcrimes House".

It is likely referring to not just one warcrime, but many that have been committed by Russia.  There are other examples where a title has had a plural modifier for the same reason (i.e. a Senior Communications Officer manages not just one communication, but many).  Also consider that "Russian Warcrime House" could be confused as an establishment that facilitates Russian Warcrime activity rather than just bringing attention to Russian Warcrimes as a concept.

Since it is a title (and art for that matter), there isn't much value in judging it from a grammatical perspective.  And as the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) referenced by the linked answer suggests, sometimes a title like this has a plural noun modifier for stylistic reasons.

Comment: The referenced question is not really answered by its only answer, btw

Comment: I assume you mean that it does not explain when one should be used over the other.  I believe this is because you can't cover every possible scenario exhaustively, and the choice is often subjective. It depends on context and appears to be up to personal preference in many cases.